# Why pushed array is not persisted?

Tags: php

I am trying to build a nested tree out of linear paths,
the paths I have are sorted from parent toward children, like this:

```
$paths= array(array(999, 10, 9, 8, 7), array(999, 10, 9, 82, 75), array(999, 10, 9, 83, 74));
```

where 10 is child of 999, 9 is a child of 10, and 8 is a child of 9, etc..

The tree_root has 999 id, which will present the top node of the tree.

```
$tree_root = array('id' => 999, 'nodes' => array());
```

The problem I have is that the `buildTree` will not add persisted new children into the `tree_root`, insertion works ONLY inside tree_root direct children, any inserted nodes inside children of tree_root's children will not be there after returning from buildTree function, any idea how to retain references and solve this?

```
// loop of sorted paths:
for ($i = 0; $i < count($paths); $i++) {
  for ($l = 0; $l < count($paths[$i]) - 1; $l++) {
    $this->buildTree($tree_root, $paths[$i][$l], $paths[$i][$l + 1]);
  }
}

public function buildTree(&$a, $parent_id, $child_id)
    {
        if ($a["id"] == $parent_id) {
            $exists = false;
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($a["nodes"]); $i++) {
                if ($a["nodes"][$i]["id"] == $child_id) {
                    $exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!$exists) {
                $node_template_children = array();
                $node_template = array('id' => $child_id, 'nodes' => &$node_template_children);
                $node_template = &$node_template;
                $a_nodes = &$a["nodes"];

                // $a_nodes is not affected when returning from buildTree!!
                array_push($a_nodes, $node_template); 
            }
            return true;
        }
        foreach ($a["nodes"] as $node) {
            $result = $this->buildTree($node, $parent_id, $child_id);
            if ($result == true) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: it would help if you provided a copy-pastable way for us to test out your method... you can edit your post to do that

Comment: I have copied the $paths variable, please check above, the other code is already copied and pasted

Comment: I suspect you're missing the fact that `foreach` also just works on a copy of the array, unless you explicitly use a reference there too...!? `foreach ($a['nodes'] as &$node)`...

Comment: @deceze thanks! you made my day :)